# How to draw two curves in one plot / graph

Tags: r

I have two functions, with a range-specific argument. I can’t get them on one chart in any way.

```
f1 = function(x1){
  return (sqrt(64-x1^2))
  }

f2 = function(x2){
  return (cos(x2) - x2)
}

plot(f1,-5, 1) 
plot(f2,-pi/2, pi/2)
```

I just started to learn this language, and I do not quite understand how this process can be performed.

If I execute the code, I get the following:

[image]
[image]

I need these curves to be on the same graph

Comment: What do you mean by "to one plane"?

Comment: @vojtam, So that the two graphs are not in different windows, but in one, at the same time, their coordinate orientation relative to each other is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ggplot2` and `stat_function` to draw multiple functions and to restrict the range of each of them:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) cos(x) - x, color = "red", xlim = c(-pi/2,pi/2)) +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) sqrt(64-x^2), xlim = c(-5,1)) +
  ylim(-10,10)
```

[image: Output]

You wan still add `ylim` (as I did) and `xlim` to restrict the main panel range, but the inside-functions `xlim` will restrict the computation of the functions to theses ranges

Answer (score 2):

You can try the `lines()` argument to add to an existing plot:

```r
f1 = function(x1){
  return (sqrt(64-x1^2))
}

f2 = function(x2){
  return (cos(x2) - x2)
}


x <- c(-5:5) # choose your x value range here
y1 <- mapply(FUN = f1,x1 = x) # lets get the y values before plotting
y2 <- mapply(FUN = f2,x2 = x) # lets get the y values before plotting


plot(x,y1, type = "l", col = "red", ylim = c(-5,10))
lines(x, y2, col = "blue", type = "l")
```

Giving you this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `curve` might be quite efficient.

```
curve(sqrt(64 - x^2), col=2, xlim=c(-5, 1), ylim=c(-5, 10))
curve(cos(x) - x, col=4, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```r
f1 = function(x1){
    return (sqrt(64-x1^2))
}

f2 = function(x2){
    return (cos(x2) - x2)
}

x = seq(-5, 1, len=20)
y = cbind(y1=f1(x), y2=f2(x))

matplot(x, y, col=1:2, type="l", lty=1)
legend('topright', legend=c(expression(f[1]), expression(f[2])), col = 1:2, lty=1, bty = "n")
```

[image]